# Por que o <li> está centralizado?

Tags: html, css

```css
@charset "UTF-8";

body {
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

/* header principal */

header#main-header {
    width: 246px;
    height: 42px;
    background-color: rgb(68, 68, 68);
    margin: auto;
}

header#main-header img#main-img {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    float: left;
}

header#main-header h1#main-h1 {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    padding-top: 6px;
}

/* menu principal */

nav#main-menu ul {
    margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <title>File Manager</title>
</head>
<body>

<header id="main-header">
    <img id="main-img" src="image/svg/folder-open-regular.svg" alt="">
    <h1 id="main-h1">File Manager</h1>
</header>

<nav id="main-menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">Project</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Tutorial</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Na verdade ele não está centralizado. Está ali porque o `float: left` na tag `img` está puxando não apenas o `h1` mas também a `nav` para à direita, pegando a primeira `li`.

Não é muito recomendado usar `float: left` em várias ocasiões, mas no seu caso, você consegue resolver isso colocando a propriedade `clear: left;` na `nav`, fazendo com que ela não aceite elementos à sua esquerda, "anulando" o efeito do `float` e forçando a quebra de linha. Veja:

```css
@charset "UTF-8";

body {
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

/* header principal */

header#main-header {
    width: 246px;
    height: 42px;
    background-color: rgb(68, 68, 68);
    margin: auto;
}

header#main-header img#main-img {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    float: left;
}

header#main-header h1#main-h1 {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    padding-top: 6px;
}

/* menu principal */

nav#main-menu ul {
    margin: 0px;
}

nav#main-menu{
    clear: left;
}
```

```html
<header id="main-header">
    <img id="main-img" src="image/svg/folder-open-regular.svg" alt="">
    <h1 id="main-h1">File Manager</h1>
</header>

<nav id="main-menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">Project</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Tutorial</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```